# using NtQueryDirectoryFile in c#?

Tags: c#, winapi, directory, pinvoke

how to use "NtQueryDirectoryFile" in c# and is it considered a bad practice to use undocumented winapi functions? also is there a faster alternative ?

*by the way the performance of enumeration is crucial in the application I'm developing ,and this isn't premature optimization  ?

*I couldn't find it's signature on "pinvoke.net" .

Comment: It's not actually undocumented anymore, but certainly a lot more awkward to use from .NET than the higher level functions. Perhaps you should start by stating what your objective is and why you can't accomplish it with what is provided in .NET.

Comment: Is it considered bad practice? By whom? Isn't that just asking for opinion? And is there a faster alternative? Well, define your usage. This a very flexible function. How exactly are you calling it? Are there any environmental factors that impact performance? I don't think this question is a good fit for the QA format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `GetFileInformationByHandleEx`, which is the Win32 equivalent function.

See here:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364953(v=vs.85).aspx

and here:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364228(v=vs.85).aspx